# If two matrices have the same characteristic polynomial, they need not be unitarily equivalent. Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

Fact: Two matrices are unitarily equivalent, then they have the same characteristic polynomials.

I find both of the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$
 and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$ to have the same characteristic polynomials. But they are still not unitarily equivalent. I am not sure why.

Comment: Is your question just about this example? or more general? In the first case one matrix  is Hermetian and the other is not, as Alex explains. In the second perhaps say a bit about the level of generality you are aiming for.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh more general. Alex answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each square matrix $A$ by $A’$ we denote its transpose and by $A^*$ the complex conjugate of its transpose. The second matrix $B$ in your question is real-valued diagonal, so $B=B’=B*$. Then for each unitary matrix $U$ we have $(U^*BU)^*=U^*BU$, so the matrix $U^*B^*U$ is Hermitian and so it cannot be equal to the first matrix $A$ from your question.

Answer (score 3):

A implies B does not mean B implies A.

Comment: Is that the equation $A \neq P^{-1}BP$?